# Electric vehicle instrumentation

Tags: spi, automotive, can, networking

I have converted a vw bus to 112 VDC electric drive (Tesla battery modules 22.5VDC X 5 ea). There is also a 12V system for lights and instruments. The BMS supports SPI and CAN. I have no experience with either of these protocols but I am using SPI for the BMS. I have also heard of Android Automotive. I want to add a Tesla style tablet display, cameras, and proximity sensors and have expandibility. What are the pros and cons of vehicle network protocols? Can you point me to examples to learn from?

Comment: Why would you do want to do that to a VW bus? If you want a Tesla experience, go buy one.

Comment: Possible reasons are recycling, fun, learning technology, it's called "do it yourself", and it saves 20,000 dollars and two years of waiting, and tesla doesn't do a VW bus.

Comment: Your spec doesn't make much sense. What has 112VDC (you mean 12VDC?) to do with CAN and SPI and what has any of it to do with misc consumer & fluff electronics?

Comment: I’m a newbie. I’ve edited this question to elicit technical responses. It’s too late to challenge the motives of the project.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to find the most efficient way to integrate a dependable 12V rail into the car, which probably means a discrete 12V battery and BMS, charged by a DC-DC converter.
All the equipment is standard 12V or 5V.

Search google for "12 inch tablet with sim card slot" or whatever size and features you want. If no sim, then you just have to pair it with bluetooth. Tesla has a 12.3" screen so 12 will be fine.